# Parameterized Yaml and Bicep

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-bicep

I have the following set up
#1 Has bicep templates (It deploys the container registry and publishes bicep file)
#2 Has yaml as templates (Have made template of a few tasks so instead of calling multiple tasks we call the template from here which inturn performs multiple tasks).

Now there is main pipeline in the first repo that calls another yaml to deploy acr and publish the bicep templates in it. To deploy acr it calls template which has AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3 as one of the task. And then it has one more task to run an inline script to publish bicep files. Shown below:

```
// not showing all params and task details
deploy:
          steps:
          - template: templatename
            parameters:
              azureResourceManagerConnection: 
              subscriptionId: 
              resourceGroupName:     
              deploymentMode:

          - task: AzureCLI@2
            displayName: 'Publish all bicep templates'              
            inputs:
              scriptType: 'pscore'
              scriptLocation: inlineScript
              inlineScript: |
                Write-Host "Start executing script"
                  
                az bicep install
                
                $registryName = 'mycr'
                $modulePrefix = ''
                $version = 

                az bicep publish
```

Main bicep

```
resource containerRegistry 'Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries@2021-09-01' = {
  name: name
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: skuname
  }
}
```

The name above comes from parameter json file

```
"acrName": {
      "value": "mycr"
    },
```

Now I need this set up in two different subscription in different tenants. I need the same yaml files and bicep files to work as shown above. So on the basis of a boolean variable let us say IsOld. I will decide if I should opt for Tenant 1 or 2.

But I cannot have the same name for the container registry. I am stuck with how to handle this? For instance, if I use variable group I can assign a variable named containerRegName the value of the variable from variable group if IsOld is true or not. But then how should I handle it in AzureCLI task, as the name is passed as a variable in script? And how should I play with parameter for bicep to have the right name basis the Pipeline parameter IsOld?

P.S. I know it is very confusing so please feel free to ask any questions or details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I cannot have the same name for the container registry. I am stuck with how to handle this?

Azure Container Registry names need to be unique globally, this is because dns is created that publicly points to your registry. The recommended practice is to suffix a unique string on the Container Registry Name. This does mean you get some "random" characters at the end of the name, but it does facilitate the uniqueness requirement.

You can make the name deterministic by using the [uniquestring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions-string#uniquestring) function, providing the factors to make it unique (usually ResourceGroupId, but you could use the tenantId).

```
param nameseed string = 'yourappreg'

var altContainerRegName = 'cr{nameseed}${uniqueString(resourceGroup().id, nameseed, deployment().name)}'
var containerRegName = 'cr{nameseed}${uniqueString(subscription().tenantId)}'

resource containerRegistry 'Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries@2021-09-01' = {
  name: containerRegName 
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: skuname
  }
}

output id string = containerRegistry.id
output name string = containerRegistry.name
output loginServer string = containerRegistry.properties.loginServer
```

As the name of the registry will be unknown, you'll output the name in bicep and then use those outputs in your other CI/CD pipeline steps.

Comment: Thank you GordonBy for responding. As I am new I have some silly doubts, it will be helpful if you can make me understand: 1.  Why variable altContainerRegName has been created above? 2. While I understand your suggestion of using name as output variable for pipeline steps/tasks. I have to decide the name of my container registry which is coming from main.parameters.json basis a pipeline parameter. Is there a way I can do that? I am sorry if it is answered in the above response may be I could not catch it.

Comment: 1. I left the unused variable so you can see how i'd normally use UniqueString. 2. You can use the parameter name from the file as a component of the name, for sure. Thats what my `nameseed` parameter is doing.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I will try and confirm if this works for me or if I face any issue.